# UI is printing chinese symbols instead of valid text

Tags: c++, user-interface, pointers

Im trying to print some Text on my window in C++. But instead its showing weird chinese symbols.

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X1jay.png)

```
wstring s2ws(const std::string& s);
wstring tempConsole = s2ws(console);
```

```
string* consolePointer = NULL;
string console = "Unable to open file";
consolePointer = &console;//malloc(sizeof(string));
tempConsole = s2ws(*consolePointer);
LPCWSTR result = tempConsole.c_str();
TextOut(hdc, 10, 1580, TEXT(result), 19);
InvalidateRect(hWnd, NULL, TRUE);
```

```
wstring s2ws(const std::string& s)
{
    int len;
    int slength = (int)s.length() + 1;
    len = MultiByteToWideChar(CP_ACP, 0, s.c_str(), slength, 0, 0);
    wchar_t* buf = new wchar_t[len];
    MultiByteToWideChar(CP_ACP, 0, s.c_str(), slength, buf, len);
    wstring r(buf);
    delete[] buf;
    return r;
}
```

I expected "Unable to open file" as output but got weird chinese symbols.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: Ive added a picture as example

Comment: That's Korean, not Chinese. Specifically, character [U+CDCD](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/cdcd/index.htm). `0xCD` is one of the values Visual Studio uses to represent uninitialized data. So you are probably printing uninitialized garbage. I noticed that you didn't check the return value of the second `MultiByteToWideChar`. Perhaps it fails.